# Как спарсить текст из определённого места

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Отсюда нужно взять текст "Настрой на учебную деятельность" :

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <tr class="success">
            <td colspan="3">Понедельник</td>
        </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="checkTime">09<sup>15</sup>-09<sup>30</sup></td>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                                                                <td style="width: 100%;">Настрой на учебную деятельность </td>
                                                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Мой код :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://edu.mes.ru/psychologistmentor/schedules/student"
headers = {
    "Accept" : "text/css,*/*;q=0.1",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "Cookie" : "SID=80e70c00b30caa1664846f7965f6efff; _csrf=012efacf7961084fc582f3d7186436831d4be7914a5a7ab5201fb45e380abadba%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A5%3A%22_csrf%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22B6N73TcZ2II9JHkdBNqKx6ugXiFmj-41%22%3B%7D; _identity=476c25038da40d702f037e15e78081823d4bde7696ad356284302b204b5df53fa%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A50%3A%22%5B3989%2C%22Dlx8nRoFbRXzD7_l1W6SGv7CO2Ui1pb7%22%2C25920000%5D%22%3B%7D",
    "DNT" : '1',
    "Host" : "edu.mes.ru",
    "Proxy-Authorization" : "Basic OVFSaWJ5cFJZSDZBVU10NlFUSjlUQTZOOmladVZYZWNaanNidURLemoxNzZURERNSg==",
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0"
}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    subjects = [] 
    for item in weekdays:
        subjects.append({
            #здесь должно происходить добавление текста в список "subject"
            })
    print(table)


def parse():
    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("ERROR")

parse()
```

В данном куске HTML кода у нужного блока, где находится текст не обозначен класс. Как возможно его спарсить по-дркгому?

Answer (score 1):

Применительно к тому куску кода, который дан в вопросе, это будет выглядеть так.

```py
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    from bs4.element import *


    tag_html = \
        """<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <tr class="success">
            <td colspan="3">Понедельник</td>
        </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="checkTime">09<sup>15</sup>-09<sup>30</sup></td>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100%;">Настрой на учебную деятельность </td>
                                                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
"""
    soup = Soup(tag_html, 'html.parser')
    wanted: Tag = soup.find('table', class_='table').table

    print(wanted.tr.td.text.strip())

# Настрой на учебную деятельность

    print(wanted.find('td', style='width: 100%;').text.strip())

# Настрой на учебную деятельность
```

> Но вероятно возможны варианты, которые можно предугадать только увидев весь html и рассмотрев соседние схожие элементы

Comment: спасибо. Так и вышло, при работе с полным html wanted - это <class 'NoneType'>.